# $H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda, \mathbb{Z})$ → $\Lambda$ via the map $f:\gamma \mapsto \int_\gamma dz$ is surjective?

Tags: elliptic-curves, integer-lattices, elliptic-integrals

Let fix an arbitraly lattice of $\mathbb{C}$ and call it Λ.

How to prove $H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda, \mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the lattice $\Lambda$ via the map $f:\gamma \mapsto \int_\gamma dz$
?

If once the map $f$ is proved to be surjective, I finish the proof.
I already proved this map is well defined, hom, inj.

For arbitrary $nω1＋mω2$ from $Λ$, what is the original image of $f$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: May I ask with which book (if any) you are working with?

Comment: Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', chapter 6, p176,prop5.6. But the proof is omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to look at this book at some point. May I ask how you like it, and what the requirements are to follow the book? We can discuss this also in chat, if you like, or delete the comments afterwards. I am just interested in this topic myself, but at the moment learning some complex analysis.

Comment: I like this book. This book mainly addressed elliptic curves, but also we can learn algebraic number theory and Riemann surfaces and a bit of class field theory, algebraic geometry and so on. It's recommended to people looking for something like intersection of  algebraic geometry and number theory ( Indeed, this book is basic introduction to arithmetic geometry). This book requires Basic Galois theory and basic commutative ring theory and  basic number theory ( containing basic theory about local fields) and basic complex analysis.

Comment: Completely no, the question asks well definedness. This question asks subjectiveness. Please avoid comment before reading question.

Comment: This is the idea: given $\lambda \in \Lambda$, let $\gamma$ be a path in $\mathbb{C}$ starting at $0$ and ending at $\lambda$. Then the image of $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is a closed loop, hence gives a well-defined homology class $[\gamma]$, and $\int_{\gamma} dz = \lambda - 0 = \lambda$.